# Match all words not preceded by a tilde

Tags: php, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have a string that I want to match with php regex.

```
$string = "~word1 ~word2 ~word3 word4";
```

I want to match all words that are not start with ~ sign. In php I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
preg_match("/(?!~)(?<words>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_])/i", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you may use this regex with a negative lookbehind:

```sh
~(?<!~)\b\w[\w.-]*~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S5jR2R/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!~)`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if `~` is at previous position
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `\w`: Match a word character
- `[\w.-]*`: Match 0 or more of word character or `.` or `-`

Answer (score 2):

You can set a whitespace boundary to the left, and only match the allowed characters in the character class.

Note that you have to repeat character class or else you will match a single character.

```
(?<!\S)(?<words>[a-zA-Z0-9._]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DBsrSj/1)